# how to cancel file upload in extjs

Tags: extjs, file-upload

I am having a requirement to cancel the ExtJS file upload which is already in progress. 
Is there a way to cancel the ExtJS file upload which is already in progress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link from sencha forums.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?38613-File-Upload-Cancel

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am not using iframes